# XSLT2 Generate multiple outputs from a nested input structure

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I'm using XSLT 2.0 (Saxon PE 9.5) to create multiple XML files from the input, using `xsl:result-document`. Each items can contain multiple item, and within an item there's typeA and typeB. For each such type I'd like to generate and XML. 
Example:
**input.xml**:

```
<task>
  <items>
    <item>
      <typeA>
        <id>A1</id>
        ...
      </typeA>
      <typeB>
        <id>B</id>
        ...
      </typeB>
    </item>
    <item>
      <typeA>
        <id>A2</id>
        ...
      </typeA>
    </item>
  </items>
</task>
```

Desired output:
**out1_typea.xml**:

```
<task>
  <items>
    <item>
      <typeA>
        <id>A</id>
        ...
      </typeA>
    </item>
  </items>
</task>
```

**out1_typeb.xml**:

```
<task>
  <items>
    <item>
      <typeB>
        <id>B</id>
        ...
      </typeB>
    </item>
  </items>
</task>
```

**out2_typea.xml**:

```
<task>
  <items>
    <item>
      <typeA>
        <id>A2</id>
        ...
      </typeA>
    </item>
  </items>
</task>
```

I started to use the following transformation which splits based on the items:

```
  <xsl:template match="/task">
    <xsl:for-each select="items/item">
      <xsl:result-document href="out{position()}.xml">
        <task xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
          <items>
            <item>
              <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
            </item>
          </items>
          <xsl:copy-of select="../../(* except items)" />
        </task>
      </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

But don't know how to split further on the types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it just:

```
<xsl:template match="/task">
  <xsl:for-each select="items/item">
    <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
      <xsl:result-document href="out{$pos}_{name()}.xml">
        <task>
          <items>
            <item>
              <xsl:copy-of select="." />
            </item>
          </items>
          <xsl:copy-of select="../../../(* except items)" />
        </task>
      </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you Master! Just a minor question: the position is based on the position of the type elements. instead of generating out1_typeA, out2_typeB, out3_typeA how could I do the positioning based on the item, i.e: out1_typeA, out1_typeB, out2_typeA ?

Comment: I know your time is in short supply, but could you add an explanation to your answer? Or else, I could edit in explanations myself, if you prefer.

Comment: @Mathias, I'm not sure which bits need explanation. There's perhaps a dozen significant XSLT/XPath features used here, they all seem very basic to me. Which of them seems non-obvious to you?

Comment: I think your code is straightforward to understand, but in my opinion, an answer to the question "don't know how to split further on the types" would improve the answer. Something along the lines of: `xsl:for-each` statements can be nested to "split further", but make sure you keep track of the position of the outer context item in an `xsl:variable`.